# How to update two Widgets with different parents?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

How can I update the state of two same widgets which are in different parent widgets? But so as not to update the state of parent widgets (because in my case it takes some time).

Maybe this image can help to understand my issue:

[image: widgets image]

I need to update Widget1 and Widget2 without updating other widgets.

Comment: Can you include your code-snippet that will reproduce the same issue?

Comment: You did not include any code sample, but consider using a [StreamBuilder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StreamBuilder-class.html).

Comment: Hey you can use `ValueListenableBuilder` to update specific widget. For more details read [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ValueListenableBuilder-class.html)